# How to define a common performance measure of desktop computers across a medium size company

Tags: windows, performance, administration

I have 40 machines (from Windows XP to 7, different configurations) in my company and I am responsible for maintaining them. What I would like to do is to measure the impact of new updates and new software installation on the performance of these PCs.

For this purpose, I need first to have a common metric for all the computers. I thought that such a metrics, could be time needed to start MS Outlook or MS Excel, because these two application are mostly used. Second, I need a way how to measure it. I thought about wrapping, e.g., ms outlook, to track (and send to a server) every k start how much time it needs to be ready to work with.

Does anybody have any experience with measurement of PC performance across the organization? Are there any commercial solutions for this purpose?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to test new things on a test computer to see the performance differences and later deploy them to other computers? The only differences in performance would be a clear difference (slow hardware, or running a different set of software) and I guess that in such case an user would complain about it... By doing company-wide performance measures you might be decreasing performance for most users (due to traces and sending those over) just to increase the performance of some users that have rare differences. Why care about Outlook opening slower? It only happens once at boot.

Comment: As for the goal, speeding up applications: You might want to consider ReadyBoost/SSD.

Comment: @TomWij, unfortunately there is always a "small" difference between tests and reality, which makes people unhappy and frustrated. Outlook was just an example.

Comment: But I don't think everyone would feel unhappy and frustrated, only a small share which should report that to you... But anyway, heading for a solution XPerf seems the best way to go as it provides you with the best details to help you troubleshoot the problem right away. But you will meet other problems if you want automation: How would it decide when an application is done loading? It might be waiting for a time-out instead. How are you going to do the tracing in non-invasive way? The application would have to wait for XPerf to start tracing and you would have an I/O impact afterward...

Comment: I was wondering exactly the same: how to benchmark a computer that's not a fresh install?

Comment: @TomWij, I want to get a general performance metric to know, e.g., that a last patch slowdown certain machines or installed software makes Outlook starts in 8 minutes. So I get information (after week of collecting data) that I make a change which slowed down 20% of my machines.

Comment: You users are that general performance metric, if Outlook takes 8 minutes to start instead of 5 seconds it would amaze me if your users wouldn't report that to you. If you don't want your users to be that general performance metric then you should be doing the commonly used Test Lab Deployment technique and avoid all major performance problems. This would leave you with only minor performance problems for which it wouldn't be worth going to all the hurdles to create a complex Performance Assessment system with tools like XPerf and Data Mining techniques...

Comment: @IvoFlipse: What do you mean? Comparing an used install to a fresh one?

Comment: No, what use is a benchmark on a fresh install if I'm going to use it loaded with loads of apps? @TomWij

Comment: @IvoFlipse: You are "wondering exactly the same" but nobody has ever spoken of a "fresh install", I don't understand what you are talking about. But to answer your question out of its context: Benchmarking a fresh install can be useful so you have a reference log file that contains information how the computer performs when it is fresh (Boot Time, Idle CPU, Idle I/O, ...) which you can later computer your used install with (and ask yourself "why does it take 30 seconds more to boot?"). Another use could be to see how the installed drivers are performing, accompanied with Driver Verifier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the new XPERF tool to measure the boot speed of our XP and windows 7 machines.  We were especially looking at Disk IO, since that was our biggest bottleneck on our old systems.  (we used the graphs and charts to prove our need for SSD's in our laptops).  The readability is excellent, and you can really drill down in and see what is causing delays.  I really recommend the [Pigs can Fly](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303142051/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/16/using-xperf-to-take-a-trace.aspx) blog on MSDN for a good intro.  One thing it is lacking however is a good way to programatically compare two results. We would just load two graphs up side by side, and adjust the viewing area to be the same scale, and compare visually.  We mostly use the xbootrace feature of XPERF, since boot speed is what we care about most for our very mobile workforce.

You could pick a sample of a few machines, and keep a history of their boot graphs over time.

Comment: XPerf has support for exporting things to CSV, XML and Plain-Text. I suppose it would be possible to programmatically extract useful information, although it can take quite some time before you can come up with a script that generates really useful reports...

Comment: Can I declare an events on which XPERF should start to measure? E.g., a user starts outlook or Firefox? I ask because I have already an experience of being a user when I had problems with my PC but according to an administrator everything worked fine and fast.

Comment: There would be two options for progress start, either create a batch/script to start and stop the tracing yourself (but you would have to do this for everything you want measured) or you would write a system hook but then too much will be traced (as you really don't want every executable to be traced). If an administrator doesn't have the same experience he hasn't gathered enough information (what is slow?), didn't the right measures (do a cold trace) and hasn't applied the right fixes and prevention...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from XPerf, another idea is to schedule kernel loggers and to use [Performance Analysis of Logs](http://pal.codeplex.com/) to get useful Performance related information from those logs, this won't show you a progress on the start times of the applications but will show you a more general Performance related issues.

After gathering the logs you won't have to worry about processing them yourself, you could batch process them and then check the different HTML files for issues. Just an example of that might be a huge memory leak on one of your computers, XPerf won't show that in its traces and neither will an application checking the start up times of your applications.

You could set up something that checks the memory for that purpose, but why take so much effort if there are already loggers on your system that provide you with a wealth of other useful information...